# Spring ignore duplicates with two unique identifiers

Tags: sql, spring, kotlin

I have a table in my database that has a date property, and an 'item, as well as some other basic properties. It also has a manyToOne relationship with another object.

My program runs once a day, at the end of the day when a daily report gets sent to me in the form of a CSV. At that point, I dump all that data in the csv file to my database by iterating over it. There is also a column in the database that is not altered by the CSV, and is manually edited from my sites frontend.
Please note, the data is unique to the item AND day. There will be more than one item for each day.

The issue I'm having is as the CSV report contains data for all the week so far (Mon-Friday) on a tuesday, when it tries to reinsert mondays data, it throws a duplicate error as the row already exists in the database. This makes complete sense, and of course happens for every day that is not monday.

The issue I'm facing is I need all previous days data to override only if the autoload value is set to false.

I'm not sure if this makes 100% sense, I was unsure of the best way to communicate this so please see below code.

```kotlin
@Table(uniqueConstraints = [UniqueConstraint(columnNames =["item", "customObjectTwo_date"])])
@Entity
data class PCA (
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id:Long = 0,
    @ManyToOne
    val customObjectTwo: CustomObjectTwo,
    val item:String,
    val amount: Double,
    val autoload:Boolean
)
```

As mentioned above, the data from the CSV file should only overwrite the existing data if autoload is set to false, it's a considerable amount of rows as well, so I am unsure if retrieving the object beforehand will be resource intensive.

Thanks in advance